# Hiding certain columns in column chooser in jqgrid when grid is loaded for first time

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide certain columns in to the hidden section of the  **chooser plugin** only when my grid is loaded for the **first time**.

Now, when a user chooses certain columns from **hide section** to **show column section**, and if he reloads again, The columns he had chose to show in the grid before reload,  must persist.

Is their a way to achieve this scenario?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have access to your database for writing information to it or do you only have read access?

Answer (score 0):

This will take a little work to setup.  The basic idea is to attach a function to the pager onClickButton of the chosser plugin, save this data either locally or in a database, then use the .jqGrid('showCol') method before you load your grid.  It should be noted that this is not designed for multilingual installations.

First, assuming your grid has an ID of **grid** pager has as ID of **pager** (you can choose whichever *ui-icon* you want, but I just think that the vertical dots look a little like a column)

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{caption:'',title:'Columns',buttonicon:'ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical',id:'pager-colsel',onClickButton:function(){
        $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser',{
            done:function(){
                var aryShow = new Array(),aryHide = new Array();
                //this is predetermined by the plugin and is simply #colchoose_YOURGRID
                $('#colchooser_grid option').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).is(':selected')){
                        aryShow.push($(this).html());
                    }else{
                        aryHide.push($(this).html());
                    }
                });
                //saves the selected columns as a string for storage
                var show = aryShow.join(),hide = aryHide.join();
                //now you need to store this variable somehow, either through $.post, localstorage, or a cookie
                localStorage.setItem('chooser-show', show);
                localStorage.setItem('chooser-hide', hide);
            }
            //forces user to make a choice before proceeding
            ,modal:true
        });
    }
});
```

Next, you need to grab the variable when you first load the grid.  After you call the .jqGrid initialization method, use the following code to show

```
//explodes the stored strings into proper arrays for jqGrid
var aryShow = localStorage.getItem('chooser-show').split(',');
var aryHide = localStorage.getItem('chooser-hide').split(',');
//uses the hideCol and showCol methods to load the previously stored properties
$('#grid').jqGrid('hideCol',aryHide).jqGrid('showCol',aryShow);
```

**NOTE: you will get an error if you ever change the name of any column in the colModel or if you add/delete a column.  If you are planning on modifying the colModel at all, make sure you add a code during the initialization to check for incomplete *chooser-show* and *chooser-hide* localStorage variables and delete them.